# Retrieving data from an object from an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have a list of objects like this.

I'm stuck right now, couldn't figure out how to retrieve a value of a an object, by submitting the key

```
"ListOfObjects": [
    {
        "SomethingToRetrieve": "This Is The First Value"
    },
    {
        "AnotherThingToRetrieve": "This Is Another Value "
    },
    {
        "LastToRetrieve": "This Is the Last Value"
    }
]
```

I want by creating a function :

```
retrieveValue(Key){
    // by giving as Example AnotherThingToRetrieve
    // It will return the Value of this key 
    //return "This Is Another Value "
}
```

Comment: If you try to read the content of a property that doesn't exist you will get `undefined`. Combine this with a `for` loop and you're almost done.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what is the exact goal here?

Comment: Example : 
retrieveValue(Key='SomethingToRetrieve'){
 return "This Is Another Value "
}

Comment: @LisaLearningLinux see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` over your json. `Object.keys(e)` will give you `keys` inside object literals.

1. Loop through `JSON`
2. Loop through all `keys` within `Object literal {}`
3. Match with `key` return `value` if matched.

```js
var ListOfObjects= [{"SomethingToRetrieve": "This Is The First Value"},{"AnotherThingToRetrieve": "This Is Another Value "},{
        "LastToRetrieve": "This Is the Last Value"}]
function getVal(key){
  ListOfObjects.forEach(function(e){//step #1
     Object.keys(e).forEach(function(eachKey){//step #2
       if(key == eachKey){//step #3
         console.log(e[key]);
         return ;
       }
     })
   })
   
   // one liner using find
   alert(Object.values(ListOfObjects.find(el=>Object.keys(el).find(ee=>ee==key))))
}
getVal('AnotherThingToRetrieve');
```

You can also use `find` The `find()` method returns the value of the `first element in the provided array` that satisfies the provided testing function.Inside commented statement under alert.

Comment: This only works with objects that have only one property.

Comment: OPs function is named `retrieveValue`. If the singular was on purpose you might want to use `.find()` so you don't search through the whole array if there will only be one key/value to find.

Comment: @Andreas yes it will always have one value, is there a way to do it with find ?

Comment: @LisaLearningLinux `var retrieveValue = key => ListOfObjects.find(x => x[key])[key];` ... `retrieveValue("AnotherThingToRetrieve"); // "This Is Another Value"`

Comment: @subarachnid This will fail if the key cannot be found in

Comment: @Andreas true. Here is a better version: `var retrieveValue = key => (ListOfObjects.find(x => x[key]) || {})[key];`

Answer (score 0):

You could filter all objects that have that key and then return the value from the first matching object. If you leave off the `[0]` at the end you'll get an array of all matching values.

```js
var listOfObjects = [
    {
        "SomethingToRetrieve": "This Is The First Value"
    },
    {
        "AnotherThingToRetrieve": "This Is Another Value "
    },
    {
        "LastToRetrieve": "This Is the Last Value"
    }
]


const retrieveValue = key => listOfObjects.filter(x => x[key]).map(x => x[key])[0];

console.log(retrieveValue("AnotherThingToRetrieve"))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This is pretty what i want to do could you please explain me the filter --> map how we arrived to this result please ?
Sorry i'm still learning

Comment: @LisaLearningLinux, the filter method creates a new array by filtering out all the elements that do not pass the provided function - to pass the test the function must return a true (or truthy) value. In this case it returns a truthy value if `x` (the current element) has the needed property `key` (unless it is an empty string). The map-method creates a new array of the same length, and transforms each element by applying the given function to it. In this case we extract the value for the given key `x[key]`. Now we have an array containing all matching values.

Answer (score 0):

You have a nested array. You can run a nested `for` loop to iterate through it until you find a match like so:

```js
var listOfObjects = [
    {
        "SomethingToRetrieve": "This Is The First Value"
    },
    {
        "AnotherThingToRetrieve": "This Is Another Value "
    },
    {
        "LastToRetrieve": "This Is the Last Value"
    }
]

var key = "LastToRetrieve";
console.log(retrieveValue(key));

function retrieveValue(Key){
    // by giving as Example AnotherThingToRetrieve
    // It will return the Value of this key 
    //return "This Is Another Value "
    var value = "";
    for(var obj in listOfObjects) {
       for(var item in listOfObjects[obj]) {
          if(item === key) {
               value = listOfObjects[obj][item];
               break;
          }
       }
    }
    return value;
}
```